# JSON: referencing previously defined element

Tags: json, element

The following is some sample data defined in ruby, and I would like to encode it into json, so I can import and reuse this same data in other languages.

As you can see, I have defined two variables, $datastart, and $dataend, as reusable elements.

```
$datastart = 'BEGIN: '
$dataend   = ' --- END'

$data = [
  $datastart + 'something' + $dataend,
  $datastart + 'something else' + $dataend,
  $datastart + 'yet another thing' + $dataend,
  $datastart + 'no more' + $dataend,
]
```

I'd like to write some json in which something corresponds to $datastart and $dataend, so if I want to add new entries to my list, I can manually do so within the json file itself, while referencing the json-ized $datastart and $dataend.

I know I can do this by embedding some sort of special tokens within the json to stand for $datastart and $dataend, and then substituting those tokens from within my application, *after* importing the json.

However, I don't want to write any special code within my application. I just want to do a json.load (or its equivalent), and have the data properly realized as soon as it's loaded.

I haven't found any way to do this. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON files cannot reference anything else in their file. You will either need to process the file before or after it's  created, as you thought you might.

I will note: JSON isn't really designed to be edited by hand. If you can, you might look into the [YAML](http://camel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/yamlref.html) format, instead. It can do a lot of things, is a superset of JSON (every JSON file is a valid YAML doc), and even has support for the feature you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check YAML again, but I'm pretty sure that it doesn't do string concatenation.